# Convert PHP to ASP?

Tags: php, asp.net

I have a template that uses a 3 PHP files.

connector-fileimport.php
connector-icon.php
elFinder.class.php

Is it possible to have these converted to asp.net?

connector-fileimport.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(0); // Set E_ALL for debuging

if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
}

include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elFinder.class.php';

/**
 * Simple example how to use logger with elFinder
 **/
class elFinderLogger implements elFinderILogger {

    public function log($cmd, $ok, $context, $err='', $errorData = array()) {
        if (false != ($fp = fopen('./log.txt', 'a'))) {
            if ($ok) {
                $str = "cmd: $cmd; OK; context: ".str_replace("\n", '', var_export($context, true))."; \n";
            } else {
                $str = "cmd: $cmd; FAILED; context: ".str_replace("\n", '', var_export($context, true))."; error: $err; errorData: ".str_replace("\n", '', var_export($errorData, true))."\n";
            }
            fwrite($fp, $str);
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }

}

$opts = array(
    'root'            => '../../../../examfilemanager/',                       // path to root directory
    'URL'             => "examfilemanager/", // root directory URL
    'rootAlias'       => 'Home',       // display this instead of root directory name
    //'uploadAllow'   => array('images/*'),
    //'uploadDeny'    => array('all'),
    //'uploadOrder'   => 'deny,allow'
    // 'disabled'     => array(),      // list of not allowed commands
    // 'dotFiles'     => false,        // display dot files
    // 'dirSize'      => true,         // count total directories sizes
    // 'fileMode'     => 0666,         // new files mode
    // 'dirMode'      => 0777,         // new folders mode
    // 'mimeDetect'   => 'internal',       // files mimetypes detection method (finfo, mime_content_type, linux (file -ib), bsd (file -Ib), internal (by extensions))
    // 'uploadAllow'  => array(),      // mimetypes which allowed to upload
    // 'uploadDeny'   => array(),      // mimetypes which not allowed to upload
    // 'uploadOrder'  => 'deny,allow', // order to proccess uploadAllow and uploadAllow options
    // 'imgLib'       => 'mogrify',       // image manipulation library (imagick, mogrify, gd)
    // 'tmbDir'       => '.tmb',       // directory name for image thumbnails. Set to "" to avoid thumbnails generation
    // 'tmbCleanProb' => 1,            // how frequiently clean thumbnails dir (0 - never, 100 - every init request)
    // 'tmbAtOnce'    => 5,            // number of thumbnails to generate per request
    // 'tmbSize'      => 48,           // images thumbnails size (px)
    // 'fileURL'      => true,         // display file URL in "get info"
    // 'dateFormat'   => 'j M Y H:i',  // file modification date format
    // 'logger'       => null,         // object logger
    // 'defaults'     => array(        // default permisions
    //  'read'   => true,
    //  'write'  => true,
    //  'rm'     => true
    //  ),
    // 'perms'        => array(),      // individual folders/files permisions    
    // 'debug'        => true,         // send debug to client
    'archiveMimes' => array(),      // allowed archive's mimetypes to create. Leave empty for all available types.
    // 'archivers'    => array()       // info about archivers to use. See example below. Leave empty for auto detect
     'archivers' => array(
        'create' => array(
            'application/x-gzip' => array(
                'cmd' => 'tar',
                'argc' => '-czf',
                'ext'  => 'tar.gz'
                )
            ),
        'extract' => array(
            'application/x-gzip' => array(
                'cmd'  => 'tar',
                'argc' => '-xzf',
                'ext'  => 'tar.gz'
                ),
            'application/x-bzip2' => array(
                'cmd'  => 'tar',
                'argc' => '-xjf',
                'ext'  => 'tar.bz'
                )
            )
        )
);

$fm = new elFinder($opts); 
$fm->run();

?>
```

connector-icon.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(0); // Set E_ALL for debuging

if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
}

include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elFinder.class.php';

/**
 * Simple example how to use logger with elFinder
 **/
class elFinderLogger implements elFinderILogger {

    public function log($cmd, $ok, $context, $err='', $errorData = array()) {
        if (false != ($fp = fopen('./log.txt', 'a'))) {
            if ($ok) {
                $str = "cmd: $cmd; OK; context: ".str_replace("\n", '', var_export($context, true))."; \n";
            } else {
                $str = "cmd: $cmd; FAILED; context: ".str_replace("\n", '', var_export($context, true))."; error: $err; errorData: ".str_replace("\n", '', var_export($errorData, true))."\n";
            }
            fwrite($fp, $str);
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }

}

$opts = array(
    'root'            => '../../../../examicon/',                       // path to root directory
    'URL'             => "examicon/", // root directory URL
    'rootAlias'       => 'Home',       // display this instead of root directory name
    //'uploadAllow'   => array('images/*'),
    //'uploadDeny'    => array('all'),
    //'uploadOrder'   => 'deny,allow'
    // 'disabled'     => array(),      // list of not allowed commands
    // 'dotFiles'     => false,        // display dot files
    // 'dirSize'      => true,         // count total directories sizes
    // 'fileMode'     => 0666,         // new files mode
    // 'dirMode'      => 0777,         // new folders mode
    // 'mimeDetect'   => 'internal',       // files mimetypes detection method (finfo, mime_content_type, linux (file -ib), bsd (file -Ib), internal (by extensions))
    // 'uploadAllow'  => array(),      // mimetypes which allowed to upload
    // 'uploadDeny'   => array(),      // mimetypes which not allowed to upload
    // 'uploadOrder'  => 'deny,allow', // order to proccess uploadAllow and uploadAllow options
    // 'imgLib'       => 'mogrify',       // image manipulation library (imagick, mogrify, gd)
    // 'tmbDir'       => '.tmb',       // directory name for image thumbnails. Set to "" to avoid thumbnails generation
    // 'tmbCleanProb' => 1,            // how frequiently clean thumbnails dir (0 - never, 100 - every init request)
    // 'tmbAtOnce'    => 5,            // number of thumbnails to generate per request
    // 'tmbSize'      => 48,           // images thumbnails size (px)
    // 'fileURL'      => true,         // display file URL in "get info"
    // 'dateFormat'   => 'j M Y H:i',  // file modification date format
    // 'logger'       => null,         // object logger
    // 'defaults'     => array(        // default permisions
    //  'read'   => true,
    //  'write'  => true,
    //  'rm'     => true
    //  ),
    // 'perms'        => array(),      // individual folders/files permisions    
    // 'debug'        => true,         // send debug to client
    'archiveMimes' => array(),      // allowed archive's mimetypes to create. Leave empty for all available types.
    // 'archivers'    => array()       // info about archivers to use. See example below. Leave empty for auto detect
     'archivers' => array(
        'create' => array(
            'application/x-gzip' => array(
                'cmd' => 'tar',
                'argc' => '-czf',
                'ext'  => 'tar.gz'
                )
            ),
        'extract' => array(
            'application/x-gzip' => array(
                'cmd'  => 'tar',
                'argc' => '-xzf',
                'ext'  => 'tar.gz'
                ),
            'application/x-bzip2' => array(
                'cmd'  => 'tar',
                'argc' => '-xjf',
                'ext'  => 'tar.bz'
                )
            )
        )
);

$fm = new elFinder($opts); 
$fm->run();

?>
```

The third file was too big to include in this post.  But is this even possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible to convert it. Just throw it out, and rewrite it in ASP (hopefully ASP.NET and not the wretched "classic" ASP). So, where is the [real] question?

Comment: Sure, generally any language can be converted to any other if you put enough sweat into it.

Comment: Def. possible. Are you looking for someone to do it for you?

Comment: @RPM I was hoping for some tool/converter already available.  Unless someone wants to do it, which I doubt, it looks like I will have to recreate this in asp.net.

Comment: I would do it if I was an expert in ASP. Unfortunately I've never touched on ASP

Comment: Tools that convert code from language X to language Y usually cause code nobody wants to work with, ever. The only exception is between similar languages such as C# and VB.net since they are almost the same except the syntax.

Comment: Sorry I realize the title was a bit misleading, it was convert it to asp.net not classic asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though there may exist some automated tool, I would strongly opt against it. Every language has its specifics and raw convert is rarely a good idea.

Do as other suggested - rewrite it yourself, don't rely on some tool.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this (I have no idea what it is because I don't know what asp exactly does)

http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/migration-assistants/php-to-aspnet

Comment: Tried that, could not get it to work unfortunately.  Was hoping to find a converter of some sort and not having to re-write thousands of lines of code over.

Comment: @JamesWilson It is not possible to convert this automatically. Unless AI has *far* surpassed my knowledge, it requires a human developer to rewrite it with the same intent/semantics. Parts could be converted, but alas... and as far as developers, SO is *not* a recruitment site ;-)